# using ssh-agent for authentication in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh, clion

I'm trying to use IntelliJ (well, actually CLion) with Perforce via ssh.
In order for this to work, the key needs to be loaded permanently.  Normally this works for me with ssh-agent, for which i enter the key password once and it keeps it loaded.  However, when I launch CLion, it doesn't see the ssh-agent at all and prompts me to enter password for every p4 command it runs, which is not exactly workable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I ended up with is using keychian (http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) to load the keys into the ssh-agent and then added

```
source ~/.keychain/`hostname`-sh
```

to the clion startup script (clion-2017.1.1/bin/clion.sh)